# Merge [dtd] and [xml-dtd] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dtd) and [xml-dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-dtd) are basically the same things but separate tags.

Please merge/make a synonym.

Comment: DTDs are not just an XML thing. They are also used with SGML, which predates XML. I found 8 questions tagged [tag:dtd] [tag:sgml]. XML DTDs and SGML DTDs are not generally compatible.

Comment: if, then it should be xml-dtd --> dtd, because dtd is not restricted to xml...

Comment: @Louis Every xml-dtd question is a dtd question. Agree with Vogel612. I came across this on a question which was in xml-dtd but not in dtd.

Answer (score 2):

As Louis mentions in a comment:

> DTDs are not just an XML thing. They are also used with SGML, which predates XML. I found 8 questions tagged [dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dtd) [sgml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sgml). XML DTDs and SGML DTDs are not generally compatible.

DTD is a broader concept and therefore, merging [xml-dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-dtd) to [dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dtd) makes more sense (what Vogel mentions). However, there are some questions that contain just the [xml-dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-dtd) tag and no other ones. These need to be taken care of first.

The ideal way here would be:

1. Add the [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) tag for all [the questions in the [xml-dtd] tag that do not have the [xml] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxml-dtd%5D+-%5Bxml%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0): This is completed thanks to Shog9.
2. Merge [xml-dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-dtd) to [dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dtd): This is partially completed. I have added the [xml-dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml-dtd) as a synonym for [dtd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dtd). If there are no other problems with it, I will merge them in a few days.