# Should we do anything about questions that have more than 5 tags on them?

Tags: discussion, tags, bulk-tagging

Disclaimer: the question does not suggest either of the options

I was writing a SEDE query for searching for a percentage of posts that have a certain amount of tags and opted for 6 tags per question as a sanity check, expecting the query to return `0`. Imagine my surprise when the query returned `126` questions.

Naturally, I checked what this witchery was about, and the [dedicated query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1273244/questions-with-more-than-5-tags-edited-by-community-user) returned 142 questions and made the circumstances clear: 6<sup>th</sup> tag got added as a result of actions on mass retagging following up on certain meta discussions reaching a consensus.

Related meta Q&As (not an exhaustive list yet) are:

[android-music-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-music-player) [Burn / Synonym the [music-player] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382489/burn-synonym-the-music-player-tag/382508#382508) 
[beanstalk-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beanstalk-svn) [Merge [beanstalk], [elastic-beanstalk], and [amazon-elastic-beanstalk] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275104/merge-beanstalk-elastic-beanstalk-and-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-tags) 
[docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) [Merge tags [docker-for-windows], [docker-on-windows] and [docker-windows]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355053/merge-tags-docker-for-windows-docker-on-windows-and-docker-windows) 
[http-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-post)  [Retag HTTP verbs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262349/retag-http-verbs) 
[gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson) [Nuke the [android-gson] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314454/nuke-the-android-gson-tag) 
[mongolab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongolab) and [python-mlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-mlab) [Tag ambiguity [mlab] and [mongolab]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355117/tag-ambiguity-mlab-and-mongolab) 
[xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) [Merge [dtd] and [xml-dtd] tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274916/merge-dtd-and-xml-dtd-tags/385981#385981)

The question is - what should we do to such questions:

Leave them be, remove one of the more abstract tags, or something else?

---

I found an old Meta SE question similar to that situation, and it seems that the policy back in the day was to fix them, but that was nearly 8 years ago and thus may be outdated: [How is it possible for a question to have more than 5 tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126455/how-is-it-possible-for-a-question-to-have-more-than-5-tags)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would vote to move on. These would be fixed by itself, when someone [updates the post organically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6944X.png), rather than by going through a list of affected posts. I checked a few of the posts, the presence of the 6th tag doesn't seem to be negatively affecting the post. We can totally leave it as is.

The issue with updating them now, is that they would all be bounced to the front page. This would defeat the purpose of getting Shog to do the mass re-tagging, instead of writing up a mass re-tag script ourselves.

Comment: Bhargav, sure, that is one of the possibilities I considered - no problem with leaving as is.

Comment: Sorry for asking a noob question, but why is the question's being bumped to the front page a problem? I don't really understand the explanation.

Comment: @10Rep it is less a problem with any question in particular getting bumped to the front page, and more a problem with 142 questions all getting bumped to the front page at around the same time for no particularly useful benefit, which would push more or less all current content off the front page.

Comment: @RyanM Makes sense. Especially since a lot of these questions are not that great.

Comment: Shog who is no longer with us?